# .htaccess Remove PHP get data from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

Well I'm making profile pages so right now it looks like this

```
http://example.com/random/?user=Robert
```

What I want to do is remove `?user=` from the URL so the page appears as

```
http://example.com/random/Robert
```

Iv'e searched and I can't find anything working for me.
Thanks!

Comment: Use the term "clean urls .htaccess" in Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to make all of your links in this form `http://example.com/random/Robert`, then in the htaccess file in your document root, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^random/(.+)$ /random/?user=$1 [L]
```

But to handle 301 redirects to your old URLs, you can include this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /random/\?user=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^random/$ /random/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's not working, just getting a 404, typed and clicking a link.

Comment: @NardCake What excactly are you trying to accomplish? Getting the URLs to work (such that the user types `/random/Username` as an 'alias' for `/random/?user=Username`) or the other way around (rediredting `/random/?user?Username` to `/random/Username`)?

Comment: I'm trying to get it so users can type random/username.

Comment: @NardCake Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled? And you have `AllowOverride FileInfo` (or `All`) allowing you do use things like mod_rewrite in htaccess files? Or that you don't have any other rewrite rules in your htaccess that has precidence?

Comment: @Jon Lin Well I'm using a host so i'm not sure, the only thing I have used it Deny from all to protect my source code.  Is there a way to tell?

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html this should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^random$ random/$1             [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: If you want to go the other way (as in making the URLs work as that in the first plas), there are plenty of samples around the interweb. Jon Lin's answer below covers that.